# Move answers to same column after form submission using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I have a form that splits in to English and French but is asking the same question.

**From this**

| Column A | Eng1 | FR1 | Eng2 | FR2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row 1 | eng | fr | eng | fr |
| row 2 | eng | rf | eng | rf |

**to this**

| Column A | Eng1&FR1 | Eng2&FR2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row 1 | eng+fr | eng+fr |
| row 2 | eng+fr | eng+fr |

I am trying to move responses after the is submitted to the same column for the same questions

Here is a script I found tried but I can't get it to work even when just editing the doc without the form submission trigger.

I need to use a script and not a formula because the data will be moved from sheet to sheet afterwards using a another script.

It can be a copy or move and delete

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Responses" && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value== "") {
    const tsh=e.source.getSheetByName('New');
    const nr=tsh.getLastRow()+1;
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,12).moveTo(tsh.getRange(nr,1,1,12));
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,16,1,4).moveTo(tsh.getRange(nr,1,1,12));
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Comment: onEdit trigger  does not fire on form submission.  Try onFormSubmit trigger for spreadsheets or forms ... you pick which one you want

Answer (score 0):

What about a formula like this?:

```
=ArrayFormula({A:A,B:B&", "&C:C,D:D&", "&E:E})
```

Just in case you have another locale, if this gives error try:

```
=ArrayFormula({A:A\B:B&", "&C:C\D:D&", "&E:E})
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, if you need to make a script from when a form is submitted you should explore: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder